# How to get the value of a custom tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-tag

I have a custom tag with format

```
<ie:menuitems id="ieMenu">Hello World</ie:menuitems>
```

Now my task is to change the 'Hello World' text, but I am unable to retrieve the value with jQuery/JavaScript, i can get the element for sure because $('#ieMenu").size() gives me 1 as output, but to get the value i tried .text(), .contents(), .val(), .html()  but none worked, please help

thanks in advance

EDIT--------------------------------------------------

I think I should mention something here, the above code sample is copied from the page source, i am not sure if this helps you in some way or not, what i wanted to say this is the converted html, and i am running my code in a button click not in page load

Comment: What's the HTML that this custom tag is generating on the browser/DOM?

Comment: are you trying to run this in IE? a quick test in Chrome for $('#ieMenu').html(); returns "HelloWorld"

Comment: it's a custom menu generated in ie only, i have to run the code in ie

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ alert($('#ieMenu').html());}); works

Comment: if you can make a http://jsfiddle.net/ we might be able to help u

Comment: @Diptarag, have you verified with nextSibling.nodeValue as shown in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazing I don't know is it correct or not but I checked and found "Hello World" by using

```
$("#ieMenu")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue
```

and you can assign value as

```
$("#ieMenu")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "Test"
```

Comment: Hey thanks bro!! I dont understand the logic, but this seems to work, checked in console, will put in actual code

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
​$(function(){
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitems')[0];
    console.log(element.innerHTML) 
    element.innerHTML = 'another'    
})​
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WR8MH/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle which does what you want, and works for me in latest Chrome, Firefox, and Opera: http://jsfiddle.net/hTJFk/. The code is reproduced below:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <ie:menuitems id="ieMenu">Hello World</ie:menuitems>
</html>
```

​
**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#ieMenu').text("Goodbye World");
});​
```

For me, the result was that the tag contained "Goodbye World" as expected.

What browser were you testing on? I suspect that this might be a browser issue, in which case we can try and hack around it.